# Google Maps v3: checking the intersection of two polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, intersection

How to check whether polygons intersect or not?
I'm interested in the situation shown on the picture [polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KABlK.jpg)

Comment: Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37630353/5452965) SO answer, it will be helpful

Comment: Thank you, it really helped

Comment: Good job mate +1 for your efforts :)